# PowerShell Convert SharePoint Online UTC date To Local (or EST) within a Select expression

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

My PowerShell script retrieves file information from a SharePoint Online library and compares to a local repository.  However, it always returns the SPO TimeStamp value in UTC time.  I'd like to convert this to EST in order to compare to onPrem files.

```
$Target = @($TargetFiles | Select @{Label='TargetItemURL';Expression={$_.FieldValues.FileRef.Replace($Web.ServerRelativeUrl,"")}},
                            @{Label='Timestamp';Expression={$_.FieldValues.Modified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")}},
                           @{Label='FullName';Expression={$_.FieldValues.FileRef.Replace($TargetFolder.ServerRelativeURL,$SourceFolderPath).Replace("/","\")}},
                            @{Label='PSIsContainer';Expression={$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder"}})
$FilesDifferent = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Source -DifferenceObject $Target -Property FullName, Timestamp, TargetItemURL, PSIsContainer
```

How can I get the Target to contain the timestamp as local or EST?  I've tried creating a separate function call but those don't seem to work since is using the "Select" statement.

Comment: Change `$_.FieldValues.Modified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")` to `$_.FieldValues.Modified.ToLocalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")`

Comment: I knew someone here would have the straight-forward answer.  Thanks Mathias!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the format string you're passing to the `ToString()` method, I'm gonna venture a guess that `$_.FieldValues.Modified` contains a `[datetime]` value.

To localize a universal or non-local `[datetime]` value, call the [`ToLocalTime()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime):

```
@{Label='Timestamp';Expression={$_.FieldValues.Modified.ToLocalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")}},
```